# Entity Framework foreign key from interface

Tags: interface, foreign-keys, entity-framework-5

I'm a bit confused using Entity Framework 5. I created two interfaces for my entities:

[image: Interface]

Then I created the classes like the following:

**Word:**

```
public class Word : IWord
{
  [Key]
  [Required]
  public int WordId { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Tag { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Translation { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public char Language { get; set; }

  public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

  //Foreign Key
  public int VocabularyId { get; set; }

  //Navigation
  public virtual IVocabulary Vocabulary { get; set; }
}
```

**Vocabulary:**

```
public class Vocabulary : IVocabulary
{
  [Key]
  [Required]
  public int VocabularyId { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual List<IWord> Words { get; set; }
}
```

And at the end, in my `DataContext` I wrote:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Word>()
    .HasRequired(w => w.Vocabulary)
    .WithMany(v => v.Words)
    .HasForeignKey(w => w.VocabularyId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

I tried to remove the Interfaces and everything is fine ..

Any helps?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity framework cannot handle interfaces in navigation properties. It doesn't know how to materialize them. So you can keep the interfaces on the types (`class Word : IWord` etc.), but `Vocabulary.Words` should be an `ICollection<Word>`.